# Selenium IDE: Incrementing values by 1 and 71

Tags: ide, selenium

Currently I'm incrementing a value called wert by 1 with the following code:

```
getEval storedVars['wert']=${wert}+1;
```

The value 'wert' is something like 80401299.

I want to add 1 to the value, if it ends between 70 and 99, after 99 the next value should be 80401370 (skipping 00-69). How is this possible in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on what this has to do with Selenium (it looks like a matter of plain Javascript to me). Unless I'm missing something, all you need to do is check the value of `wert` modulo 100 and increment accordingly. In pseudocode:

```
if wert % 100 <= 69
    wert = wert + 71
else
    wert = wert + 1
```